# To check if the set $A$ is compact.

Tags: general-topology, analysis, compactness

$A = f(B) \subset \mathbb{R}$ where $B$ is a closed interval contained in $(0,\infty)$  and $f(t) = \log t$ 
Need to verify if $A$ is open, closed, connected, compact

My attempt : $B$ is a closed interval and $f$ is a continuous function on given interval thus  $A$ is closed. 
Since $B$ is closed and bounded and $f$ continuous and thus set $A$ will be connected set. 
The set is not open. 
I am unable to show if it is compact or not.

Comment: You say that $B$ is bounded in your second paragraph, but that was never a given in the first paragraph.

Comment: This question is already answered [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1146705/closed-connected-under-the-mapping-ft-log-t?rq=1)

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** You can do this very easily by noting that $B$ is either $[a, b] $ or $[a,\infty) $ with $a>0$.  So $f(B) $ is either $[\log(a),\log(b)]$ or $[\log(a), \infty) $.

I'll leave the conclusion for you.